# Symfony - Server runs first time then fails with CommandNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying out symfony with Lynda - Learning Symfony 3. I'm using windows 7, and I have successfully followed the steps given in the [Symfony installation page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)

The problems begins when I stop the server with ctrl-c. It never starts again. The error that the command line constantly gives is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.
```

I have looked around for two days and there is nothing that seems to work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

just use `server:start` and `server:stop`

instead of

`server:run` and `CTRL-C`